# Regex for excluding 855 numbers with or without +1s

Tags: regex

I have the following set of strings:

```
tel:+1 855 345 3455
tel:+185564354
tel:+85523456
tel:1855345445
tel:6047222733
tel:+54434553
tel:+1833453335
```

I am trying to write a regex that will omit any string value that contains an 855 number that may or may not be preceded by a 1, +, space or a combination of all three.

I tried a few but none seem to give me a 100% accurate match.

The one that seems to work for most strings is: `**^tel:[+]?[1]?[ ]?[^8][^5][^5].*$**` but it also matches these two string values:

```
tel:+1 855 345 3455
tel:+185564354
```

And I am not sure why.

Can any regex whiz help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with following regex.

**Regex:** `^(?=.*855).*$`

**Explanation:**

- `(?=.*855)` a positive lookahead for `855` anywhere in the string. If present then only whole string will be a match.

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sELRlq/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach is

```
^[1\s+]*(?:855)[\s0-9]*$
```

1. `^` is the beginning of the string.
2. `[1\s+]*` matches any of those characters 0 or more times.
3. `(?:855)` is a non-capturing group that means that `855` must be in the string.
4. `[\s0-9]*` matches any character in the class (space or digit) 0 more times.
5. `$` is end of string.

if you don't want spaces following `855` change the character class in 4. to what you want.

[working regex](https://regex101.com/r/oJppVp/1)

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach:

```
tel:(?!\+?1?\s?855).*
```

- `tel:` <- litteral match
- `(?!\+?1?\s?855)` <- negative look ahead for any numbers starting with `+1\s855` where the `+1\s` are optional, but must be in that order
- `.*` <- match for the rest of the string for strings that aren't caught by the negative lookahead.

https://regex101.com/r/pIcTHA/1